# Ramda.js - Slice Array's Inner Values

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming, ramda.js

What would be the best way to achieve this using Ramda.js?

```
function innerVals(array) {
  const lengthMinus1 = array.length - 1;
  return array.slice(1, lengthMinus1);
}
```

I cannot seem to find a good way to slice until length - 1 without storing that variable somewhere. The best I could come up with is using Ramda's converge function like this:

```
// innerVals :: Array -> Array
function innerVals(array) {
  // lengthMinus1 :: Array -> Number
  const lengthMinus1 = R.pipe(R.length, R.subtract(_, 1));

  // getVals :: Array -> Array
  const getVals = R.converge(
    R.slice(1, _, _),
    [lengthMinus1, R.identity]
  );

  return getVals(array);
}
```

I'm having a difficult time believing that this is a clean way to accomplish such a simple goal. There's significantly more code in the functional programming approach, and I also think it would be more difficult for other developers to read / maintain. Am I missing something? If anyone has a different approach, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: The title doesn't seem to match the question...

Comment: Sorry about that. Stack Overflow had my last title stored as a cookie. Changed now!

Comment: The initial implementation could be simplified to `array.slice(1, -1)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ramda has the function [`init`](http://ramdajs.com/0.19.1/docs/#init), which "returns all but the last element of the given list or string."  So

```
 R.compose(R.init, R.tail)([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]); //=> [2, 3, 4]
```

You can see this on the **[Ramda REPL](http://goo.gl/xSTIja)**

Answer (score 4):

I recommend [`R.slice`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#slice):

```
> R.slice(1, -1, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
[2, 3, 4]

> R.slice(1, -1)([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
[2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
innerVals = R.compose(
    R.drop(1),
    R.dropLast(1));

console.log(innerVals([1,2,3,4,5])) // [2,3,4]
```

or simply [`slice`](http://ramdajs.com/0.19.1/docs/#slice):

```
innerVals = R.slice(1, -1)
```

Comment: Neat solution. If slice was used, how would you supply its second parameter with length - 1 without storing it as a variable? This is what I was trying to replicate using converge, which worked. It just seemed clunky to me.

Comment: @wcarroll: `innerVals = R.slice(1, -1)`

Comment: I totally forgot about negative indexes. This is too simple. Love it. Thanks, @georg